Magic way to make :: base (e.g. Animal) class know class of its REAL self derive instance (Dog) upon "new Dog()"
I have to do a prematurely optimization improve performance of virtual function calling.
Animal::f1(int) is a virtual function.  It is implemented by many classes e.g. Dog,Cat and Murderous_Hippo.
In real world, the f1() is used as a callback with high cpu-traffic.
i.e. f1() is always called from the base class Animal, not derived classes.
e.g. animal->f1(something), not dog->f1(something)
From profiling, calling animal->f1(int) many times is so slow.
f1() is called in many places in my code, but the bottleneck happens only where it is called in a tight loop like this.
for(Animal* animal : allAnimalInTheWorld){
    for(int i : intArraySizeAround1000){
        animal->f1(i);
    }
}

Workaround 1 (fast, but hard to maintain)
My poor solution to improve it is to register the callback as a function receiving array.
Here is pseudo code :
class Animal{
    public: virtual void f1(int)=0;
    public: std::function<void(const std::vector<int>& v)> f2;
    public: template<class T> void regg{  
        f2=[&](const std::vector<int>& v){   ///<=== squeeze the array as param
            for(auto i:v){
                 static_cast<T*>(this)->f1(i);   ///<=== amazingly fast
            }
        };
    }
};
class Dog final : Animal{
    public: Dog(){  Animal::regg<Dog>(); }
};

And I can call f2 in tight loop.  It is very fast. Problem is solved.
animal->f2(vector_of_int);

However, the practice is so hard to maintain.
Every derive classes e.g. Dog,Cat and Murderous_Hippo have to remember to regg<T>() themselves.
Workaround 2 ("deducing this" - not work)
Here is another attempt using "deducing this".
I guess it doesn't work because Animal's constructor doesn't know that itself is a Dog yet.
Here is MCVE (godbolt).
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
class Animal{
    public: virtual void f1(int)=0;
    public: std::function<void(const std::vector<int>& v)> f2;
   
    ///: "deducing this" technique (not work in this case)
    public:  template <typename Self> void myReg(this Self&& self)   {
        std::cout<<"Animal::myReg ini self=" 
           <<typeid(decltype(self)).name() <<std::endl;
        self.f2=[&](const std::vector<int>& v){
            for(auto ele:v){
                 self.f1(ele);
            }
        };
    }
    int s=(myReg(),-12);
};

class Dog  final : public Animal{public:
    virtual void f1(int param){
        std::cout<<(param+1)<<std::endl; 
       ///: some fast yet complex function about 'param'
    }
};
int main(){
    Dog d;       /// print "self=class Animal", I am sad
}

How to make my callback f1() fast when calling in a tight loop with array, without pushing any dirty or hard-to-maintain code into Derived classes?
Factory class may also solve this, but the solution is just pushing some hard work to user's class again.
Edit::-
Here is a solution using CRTP. (suggested by
3CxEZiVlQ)   godbolt MCVE
It is fast and works well in my real world case.
There is a small cons that it is not much easier than my Workaround 1. (I agree with n.m.'s comment)

You seem to be looking for What is the curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP)? or TL;DR Curiously Recurring Template Pattern

@3CxEZiVlQ :: Thanks.  You understand my question so well and so fast.  I have looked into it, but I believe that, even with CRTP, I still need call "regg()" in Dog class manually?

No, you don't need it. T is known in Animal.

@3CxEZiVlQ  :: Hmm... After I think again, I think you are right.

@3CxEZiVlQ :: I have about 50 classes like Dog.  I have to refactor them all?  It is not that bad, but I prefer to avoid it if there is a better choice.

This is another question and may be off-topic as opinion-based.

CRTP likely won't let you have allAnimalInTheWorld, since Animal<Dog> and Animal<Cat> are now two distinct unrelated types.

@Igor Tandetnik  ::  Thanks, I agree.   I am modifying it by creating new class AnimalCRTP<Derived> inherit from Animal.   Dog will inherit from AnimalCRTP<Dog>.   It should work.

There is no magic way.  If you need this, your design is flawed.

@n.m.couldbeanAI :: It is a philosophy curiosity that is hard to locate.

@3CxEZiVlQ :: Your solution (CRTP) works.  My bottleneck has moved to elsewhere.  Please consider posting it as an answer.

CRTP replaces "every class must remember to register itself" with "every class must remember to derive from a template parameterized by itself". The latter may or may not be easier to  maintain than the former.

@n. m. could be an AI  :: n.m., you are certainly correct.   I just have to cope until I find a better one.

Can you change signature to virtual void f1(std::span<int>)=0; (and possibly void f1(int i) { f1(std::span(&i, 1)); } for retro-compatibility)?

@Jarod42 :: Code of Dog that implements array-version would be less simple like Dog::f1(std::span<int>){ LOOP } ?   I would like to avoid spread ugliness throughout every species.  T_T.      By the way, it is great to learn about the class std::span, thanks!

Loop seems not complicated ;-) But indeed, each derived classes would need to implement the loop version.

Re: remember to derive from a template. If you make Animal constructors private and make AnimalCRTP a friend, then Dog et al would be forced to inherit from AnimalCRTP. Deriving directly from Animal wouldn't compile.

You don't strictly need std::function and lambda, a plain function pointer should work. As in template <typename T> void F1Wrapper(Animal* self, const std::vector<int>& v) { static_cast<T*>(self)->f1(...);. Then Anmal would hold a void(*f1_wrapper)(Animal*, vector) pointer, implement void f2(vector) { f1_wrapper(this, ...); }, and the derived classes (or the CRTP mix-in) would initialize f1_wrapper = F1Wrapper<Dog>;

@cppBeginer :: How does using CRTP solve your bottleneck problem? If I understand correctly the bottleneck comes from a virtual dispatch when calling f1() via pointer to a base class. Even when using CRTP you still have to use that pointer to base class.

@Igor  ::  1.  Thanks.  Yes, that is a (small) caveat too. T_T   ;   2. Oh, thanks!  Nice to be able to remove usage of the heavy std::function.

@Wojciech :: If there is no virtual-dispatch inside f2(), even f2 itself is virtual, then (CASE1) animal->f2(arr)  is usually faster than (CASE2) for(i=0;i<100;i++){animal->f1(int);}   ----   I am not sure why.  I had believed it should not.    Even so, from my recurring experiment, experience, and suffering, I can almost feel that the code of CASE1 is compiled to animal->expensiveVirtual->LOOP100{no-expensive-virtual}; and CASE2 is compiled to for(i=0;i<100;i++){animal->expensiveVirtual->f1(int);}.  (call "expensiveVirtual" 100 times)

For reference, here is MCVE of using CRTP.  https://godbolt.org/z/Y8e6YYcv6   (The question is edited to include this link.   I may remove this comment later.)

@Wojciech The difference is one virtual dispatch for the whole vector vs one for each element. The whole point of the trick is to arrange things so f1 is called through the pointer to derived class.

@IgorTandetnik :: Is there anyone who did that before?  Is there a name for such trick so I can read more about it?

I, for one, have never seen anyone having this problem before. A virtual function call is usually not that expensive, compared to what the function itself is doing. Your f1 must be doing next to nothing, if an extra pointer indirection causes noticeable overhead.
